# Mysql crash and won't start

Tags: mysql

My mysql server crashed alone, it was a resources problem, so I copied the data files and pasted them on a new server to recover the database this is the error on the start of the new server:

The file permissions are ok :

> 1

```
60928 12:57:37 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /Applications/mampstack-5.6.26-1/mysql/data
2016-09-28 12:57:37 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-09-28 12:57:37 0 [Note] /Applications/mampstack-5.6.26-1/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin (mysqld 5.6.33) starting as process 28918 ...
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/Applications/mampstack-5.6.26-1/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-09-28 12:57:37 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If you are attempting downgrade from MySQL 5.7.9 or later,
InnoDB: please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-downgrading.html
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [ERROR] Aborting
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Binlog end
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-09-28 12:57:38 28918 [Note] /Applications/mampstack-5.6.26-1/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin: Shutdown complete
160928 12:57:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/mampstack-5.6.26-1/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
```

UPDATE

after reinstalling mysql version 5.7 i got this error on connecting mysql :

[image]

Comment: You could try checking your Mysql versions. "InnoDB: If you are attempting downgrade from MySQL 5.7.9 or later,"

Comment: thank you for your response, i updated the post after reinstalling mysql 5.7, and added the error screenshot.

Comment: You could try researching for similar issues and solutions on [Database Administrator Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could try   "[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4"    Read this article    https://www.gcsdstaff.org/roodhouse/?p=3070

Answer (score 0):

FIXED LIKE THIS :

1. reinstall mysql 5.7
2. STOP MYSQL
3. RUN : mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
4. RUN MYSQL
5. mysqldump -u root -p database > database.sql

THANK YOU ALL.

Answer (score -1):

Try with these.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1

sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1 --reinstall
```

maybe it helpfull

```
mysqlcheck --repair --databases db_name ...
```

Comment: actualy it's a mamp folder ! and the mysqlcheck can't work cause i have to connect mysql before

Comment: And it won't fix innodb table.